# Correct syntax to avoid bash 'ambiguous redirect' message

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am trying to execute a command which accumulates `stdout` into an existing file and sends the error messages to another using the command below.

`commmand >> /home/user/accumulate_output.log  2>& /home/user/error.log`
which gives this error message

`bash: /home/user/error.log :ambiguous redirect`

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2>&1` means redirection of error stream to the standard output and `&` character on its own doesn't have much meaning: it's waiting for you to provide a number of the file descriptor, but you are giving him a filename istead. You want to redirect into file, not a numbered file descriptor, so

```
commmand >> /home/user/accumulate_output.log 2>/home/user/error.log
```

You can understand `&1` and `&2` as "filenames" referring to file descriptors of stdout and stderr. Now you see that `&` in front of a filename doesn't make sense.

In summary, the syntax is `n>&m` or `n>file` where `n` is the file descriptor to redirect (if it is not specified, it means standard output, `n=1`), and on the right side, you can either redirect to file descriptor `m`, or a file with name `file`. `m` can be a number or `-` which means the file descriptor should be *closed* instead of redirected (redirected "nowhere").

There is also a special syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same place, but that's `&>`. It will just confuse you, as it doesn't fall into the regular syntax - it is a shortcut that actually performs two redirects at once.